# How to convert array of objects to array of arrays in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

`var ph = [{x:1231,y:121},{x:131,y:11},{x:231,y:21},{x:123,y:12}]`

I want to convert that to

```
[[1231,121],[131,11],..]
```

So far I have tried `Array.prototype.slice.call` but it is not working for me.

Comment: useful question, could be used for many other things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. It iterates over an array and creates new one with the items returned by each iteration:

```js
var ph = [{x:1231,y:121},{x:131,y:11},{x:231,y:21},{x:123,y:12}];

var result = ph.map(function(el) {
    return [el.x, el.y];
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre>'
```

ES6 syntax would also allow more concise notation:

```
var result = ph.map(el => [el.x, el.y]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to iterate and generate new array based on old array elements.

```js
var arr = [{
  x: 1231,
  y: 121
}, {
  x: 131,
  y: 11
}, {
  x: 231,
  y: 21
}, {
  x: 123,
  y: 12
}];

var res = arr.map(function(v) {
  return [v['x'], v['y']];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). In ES6 it can done like

```js
var ph = [{x:1231,y:121},{x:131,y:11},{x:231,y:21},{x:123,y:12}];

var arr = ph.map(elem => [elem.x, elem.y]);

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr));
```